# populating a CSV table with python: scalability

Tags: python, csv, scalability

Im a complete beginner... so tell me if i do something stupid! I'm from a medical field and i never learned to program...

I have 2 csv tables: one table with characteristics per case (Table.csv): just 1 means present, 0 means absent...

```
Characteristics\Patients, Jan, Piet, John, Frederic, Taisha
Jaundice, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0
Fever, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0
Tachycardia, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1
Familyhistory, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1
```

I made another file AccumTable.csv:

```
Characteristics\Characteristics, Jaundice, Fever, Tachycardia, Familyhistory
Jaundice, 0, 0, 0, 0
Fever, 0, 0, 0, 0
Tachycardia, 0, 0, 0, 0
Familyhistory, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

So, what I wanted to do was the following: I want to populate the AccumTable.csv with the symptoms that occur together per patient. To see if some things occur more together.

So I made this script:

```
with open('TableBLCA.csv', "rb") as tablein:
        tablereader = csv.DictReader(tablein, delimiter = '\t', lineterminator='\n')
        counter = 1 
        for row in tablereader:
            counter = counter + 1
            #print counter  
            #iterrow = row.iteritems()
            #print iterrow
            symp = row["Characteristics\Patients"]
            #print row.iteritems()
            for pat, presence in row.iteritems():
                if presence == '1':
                    for row in tablereader:
                        if row[pat] == '1':
                            assocsymp = row["Characteristics\Patients"]
                            print symp
                            print assocsymp
                            with open('AccumTable.csv', "rb") as accumtablein, open('AccumTableintermediate.csv', "wb") as accumtableout:
                                accumtablereader = csv.DictReader(accumtablein, delimiter = '\t', lineterminator='\n')
                                fieldname = accumtablereader.fieldnames
                                accumtablewriter = csv.DictWriter(accumtableout, delimiter = '\t', lineterminator='\n', fieldnames = fieldname)
                                accumtablewriter.writeheader()
                                for row in accumtablereader:
                                    if row["Characteristics\Characteristcs"] == symp:
                                        updatedrow = row
                                        number = updatedrow[assocsymp]
                                        number = int(number) +1
                                        updatedrow.update({assocsymp:number})
                                        accumtablewriter.writerow(updatedrow)
                                    else:
                                        accumtablewriter.writerow(row)
                            accumtablein.close()
                            accumtableout.close()
                            shutil.copyfile('AccumTableintermediate.csv', 'AccumTable.csv') 
                    tablein.seek(0)
                    readercount = 0
                    while  (readercount < counter):
                        next(tablereader)
                        readercount = readercount + 1


    tablein.close()
```

This works. The problem is the scalability... I always have to write the file, close it, change the name of the file and this new named filed is read again... So it can accumulate... Is there a faster method? My first table can have more than 50000 rows and 9000 columns... My 2nd file is a 50000x50000 csv file.

Thank you very much for your ideas!

Michael

Comment: Do you have to use CSV files? Another storage engine such as a RDBMS (e.g. MySQL) or in-memory store (like Redis) might be more suitable for what you're doing.

Comment: Yeah, my thought would be that this is begging for data science-ey kinds of tools.  If memory permits, I'd want to put everything in a sparse numpy matrix and do everything from there.  Pandas might also help.  But if memory is s serious constraint that won't help. (Heh, you got a spark cluster?)